# How to determine the number of isomorphic classes of planar graphs that can be obtained as planar duals of a given graph?

Tags: graph-theory, planar-graphs, graph-isomorphism

> How to determine the number of isomorphic classes of planar graphs that can be obtained as planar duals of a given graph?

```
                * ---- *
              / |    / |
             /  |   /  |
   * ----- *    |  *   |
             \  |      |
              \ |      |
                * ---- *
```

Comment: Do you mean **this** particular graph? Besides, what is your knowledge and work on this issue ?

Comment: I just gave an example so I can understand better. I just started learning graph theory. Only idea I get to find no. of isomorphic graphs possible for a given graph is by using permutation and combination. But I was not able to get it correctly